# pass data to route from javascript to yii2 href

Tags: javascript, yii2

You need to pass a parameter from the script to the route yii2.

```
   console.log('id '+id2);
       $(".modal-content #link").attr("href", "<?= Url::toRoute(['review/actionGetreviewsbuAutor','id'=>id2]); ?>")
```

http://....actionGetreviewsbuAutor?id=id2

Answer (score 0):

id2 is in client and not is available server side  so you should add  as javascrit part  eg:

```
console.log('id '+id2);
$(".modal-content #link").attr("href", 
  "<?= Url::toRoute(['review/actionGetreviewsbuAutor');?>" + "?id=" + id2);
```